# How to close JDBC connection

Tags: node.js, jdbc, connection

I have a function for execute a stored Procedure (Caché) via JDBC connection

```
async function callStored(query, callBack) {
  var hsqldb = new JDBC(jdbcconfig);
  hsqldb.initialize(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
  hsqldb.reserve(function(err, connObj) {
    if (connObj) {
      console.log("Using connection: " + connObj.uuid);
      var conn = connObj.conn;
      conn.createStatement(function(jdbcerr, statement) {
        if (jdbcerr) {
          console.log('jdbc err', jdbcerr);
        }
        statement.executeQuery(query, function(statserr, resultset) {
          if (statserr) {
            console.log('stats err', statserr);
          }
          resultset.toObjArray(function(arrayerr, results) {
            if (arrayerr) {
              console.log('arrayerr err', arrayerr);
            }
            hsqldb.release(connObj, function(relerr) {
              if (relerr) {
                console.log('relerr err', relerr);
              }
            hsqldb.purge(function(purgerr) {
                if (purgerr) {
                  console.log('purgerr err', purgerr.message);
                }
              })
            })

            callBack(results);  

          })
        })
      })
    }
  })
}
```

I want to close the connection after getting data but the connection still connecting.
How can I do?

Comment: Which Node.js JDBC library are you using?

Comment: ```var JDBC = require('jdbc')``` var jdbc = new JDBC(jdbcconfig);
```var jinst = require('jdbc/lib/jinst')``` for call cachejdbc.jar

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/CraZySacX/node-jdbc#readme

From the docs it sounds like you may not want to manually close your connections, rather just release them back to the pool. You can pass a max idle time to automatically close stale connections

"If you pass a maxidle property in the config for a new connection pool, pool.reserve() will close stale connections, and will return a sufficiently fresh connection, or a new connection. maxidle can be number representing the maximum number of milliseconds since a connection was last used, that a connection is still considered alive (without making an extra call to the database to check that the connection is valid). If maxidle is a falsy value or is absent from the config, this feature does not come into effect. This feature is useful, when connections are automatically closed from the server side after a certain period of time, and when it is not appropriate to use the connection keepalive feature."